# Prevent process from performing network scan

Tags: networking, security, network-interface

On a linux 20.04 LTS, I'm trying to stop a process from entering promiscuous mode and/or from scanning my network. To be more specific, I'll have to install LsAgent from LANSWEEPER  in a company's notebook but I don't want it scanning my home network.

so far, I've tried to create an apparmour config (testing with tcpdump) but it seems to be ignoring "deny capability net_admin".

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering if installing it in its own network namespace could be acceptable. (I don't know how to do this, so I can't give you an answer.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies well, a docker container would be an easy way to test that

Comment: The agent is not supposed to scan your network, it's supposed to scan your local machine only (if you take the developers word). See https://community.lansweeper.com/t5/scanning-your-network/introduction-to-lsagent-for-windows-linux-and-mac/ta-p/64473

Comment: And yet, there is "scanning-your-network" in the URL. Anyway I'll have to install it today, so I'll post my findings.

Comment: Good news, it seems that LsAgent really doesn't try to scan the rest of the network, although I left a firewall up just in case. Anyway, it's still a good question. I'm still curious why the "deny capability net_admin" is not working.